# Can a multiple value "lookup" column be displayed as checkboxes in a SharePoint List?

Tags: web-part, list, pivot-tables

I have one list to store information about people, and another list storing a list of tasks each person should achieve. I'm trying to create a SharePoint view which allows users to enter/modify people, and also tick off the tasks that person has achieved - each row will list the columns from the "people", list, followed columns containing a checkbox for each task row in the "tasks" list.

We are using a hosted instance of SharePoint 2010 Foundation edition. Am from an ASP.net/C# background and have just got started on SharePoint 2010 within the past week, so don't mind getting stuck into SharePoint Designer or Visual Studio to create a custom Web Part if I have to :)

Thanks in advance for any advice given.

Chris

Answer (score 1):

The OOTB lookup column supports multiple values in the following UI:
[image]

But I think you can create your own column based on lookup and implement custom field control (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff679964.aspx#bk_custfieldtype) where you will be able to get field value and render it as multiple check box. It's not so much work to do.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response and link for implementing custom field controls. The in-built way of selecting multiple values is a bit too cumbersome for us; a "grid view" is required so the user can quickly specify multiple people completing the same task. Any other suggestions for doing this OOTB appreciated....

Comment: I don't think there's any OOTB functionality to do it. :(

Answer (score 1):

Check this link: http://www.sparqube.com/sharepoint-lookup-column/. It is for edit lookup values using checkboxes.

**NOTE**: This is a commercial product.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the built-in Datasheet View:

When looking at your list, select the 'List' tab (under 'List Tools' at the top), and click 'Datasheet View' (second from left). This will allow you to enter users in an Excel-like fashion.

Multi-value lookups are displayed as a multi-select checkbox list in the DataSheet View (once the cell is selected), which I believe will suits your needs.

Comment: This is very close - thanks for pointing it out. Ideally the checkboxes should be placed horizontally, but this is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Extended Lookup Field](http://extendedlookupfield.codeplex.com/) available at Codeplex.

> This project installs a custom lookup field, which allows the user to
>   choose the item through a SharePoint 2010 popup.